# combineReducers return type is inferred to have type any

Tags: typescript, redux, jsdoc

I am using typescript on JSDocs and I am having a bad time typing the root state of my application.
Following redux documentation about how to use it with typescript, I try to use the return type of my root reducer as the root state state but it infers to be any. I'm not sure if this is just a bug on my redux version or what. Here is my code snippet:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { routerReducer } from 'react-router-redux';

const homeReducer = (state: {cool: boolean}) => state

const reducerMap = {
  router: routerReducer,
  home: homeReducer,
};

/** @typedef {ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>} RootState*/

const rootReducer = combineReducers(reducerMap);
export default rootReducer;
```

The type I'm getting out of this is `type RootState = any`.
My redux version is 3.7.2

[typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=14&ssc=28&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgYwiARsAdgUwEo4AmArsjlAM5wC%20cAZlGnAORRHEAezA3AFCiRYiOI2IxyBEmSg16jECzYBDZDAC0o8VA3sufXqiwV4ACzT520uAF44ACmNLxALkSoIAG1foInnEqxqAEobAD44R3FeAwgjeDYpcgBZJTAbRF44EQgxcldNCUtyABpMuDMQHFcKi0SoUup9AHoAKha4AAEYAE8wIhw6RAIYYigsABVenAAeHr6IQcYIGElSclDaPF8YAGUYJxwWpujDY2zl1atbVAxsWrXKOwSHlLAgvhwOQXhCAaViDzxbaXch8IA)

Comment: Remind me, `rootReducer` is a function? Please share reproducable example, I will try to help with jsdocs

Comment: just added a reproducible example and a link to the TS playground

Comment: Do you need to use JSDoc?  Any reason you can't just do `export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>`

Comment: @LindaPaiste because I don't want to mess with typescript transpilation and all the problems it brings and also all the noise it introduces. I prefer to stick to JSDoc

Answer (score 0):

So, looks that redux version 3.7.2 doesn't include proper types. Hopefully it was easy to upgrade it to 4.0.5 and now the types I posted are correct.
If anyone is interested in taking a look on the upgrade changes are on this PR:
[merge request](https://github.com/danielo515/pento-tech-challenge/pull/46/files)